# Misplaced title and author of calculus book

Tags: textbooks

While developing my notes for "integration by parts" some times back, I used a great book that must have been titled "Calculus and (with?) Analytical Geometry. I can't place the exact book anywhere since its no longer in our library.

Help me locate the true title and author of the book. Here are some of the problems I derived from the book.

$$\int{{x^5\,dx}\over \sqrt{3+x^2}}$$

$$\int{x\sqrt{2+x}\,dx}$$

$$\int{\sec^3{x}\,dx}$$

$$\int{x\cos{kx}\,dx}$$

I am absolutely grateful for any help proffered. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Do you recall any more details? Say the color of the cover, maybe the publisher even, the way it was bound. Was it an old or rather new book? Long or short? For what level was it written? Anything could help. You can [edit] the post to include this.

Comment: Perhaps you mean *Calculus and Analytic Geometry* by George B. Thomas, Jr. and Ross L. Finney, published by Addison-Wesley Publishing Company, Inc. My son used a special edition of this in his college calculus class, and I teach from a simplified version in the high-school calculus class that I teach.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are a lot of books by very similar titles to that and similar problems.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for you suggestions.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for you suggestions.

Quid, The book was oldish, with one author that sounded like Kittel or Killet (can't remember), hard cover(brownish,I guess), short but with around 600 pages.

Daulton, Thanks. I don't think its the book you have suggested but I will look it up as it seems promising on the Google overview. Maybe it will be a good alternative.

I agree with you, Chris. Believe me I have tried similar title, true, there are a woeful number of books with same title. I am verily lost, but this place is all my hope.

Comment: Are you sure the author wasn't Miller or Riddle?

Comment: Thanks Joel. It must have been Riddle. I shall check it out. Thanks again.

Comment: If it was "some time ago" then Thomas and Finney may have been just Thomas.  I guess when Thomas retired, Finney continued with the updates.  You know: adding all the important changes in calculus every 5 years!

Answer (score 2):

what about this one?
Introduction to Calculus and Analytic Geometry by Philip Gillett

[http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Calculus-Analytic-Geometry-Gillett/dp/1602299811](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1602299811)

Comment: OP hasn't returned to comment one way or the other, but I think this is a good candidate, especially if OP's native language is other than English or French, something where "G" is always a hard "G" or German/Dutch "CH" rather than sometimes a soft "J" sound. Gillett -> Killet.

Comment: If you look at the picture in Amazon, the cover looks a bit 'brownish', too. :-)